# Applet and Servlet communication block GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, servlets, applet

i'm trying call a servlet from an applet, and then display the response of the servlet in the applet gui, the problem is that when i press the button to call the servlet the GUI blocks until the response arrive, i try to put the code of the request in a thread, but however it freeze the gui, this is the code:

```
public class SearchApplet extends JApplet implements ActionListener{
    JTextField JTF_address;

public void init() {
    JLabel JL_address = new JLabel("Address: ");
    JL_address.setFont(new Font("OpenSans", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    JTF_address = new JTextField(20);
    ....
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    SearchThread search = new SearchThread();
    search.run();
}

public class SearchThread implements Runnable {

      public SearchThread() {
      }

      public void run() {

      try {
        String input = "prova";
        URLConnection con = getServletConnection();
        OutputStream outstream = con.getOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outstream);
        oos.writeObject(input);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();

        // receive result from servlet
        InputStream instr = con.getInputStream();
        ObjectInputStream inputFromServlet = new ObjectInputStream(instr);
        String result = (String) inputFromServlet.readObject();
        inputFromServlet.close();
        instr.close();

        // show result
        JTF_address.setText(result);

      } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
         System.out.println(ex.toString());
       }
    }
  }

}
```

how i can do?

Comment: Move your communications out of the GUI thread.

Comment: "How can I write a multithreaded application" is too general and too a question for Stack Overflow, I think. There are lots of tutorials on multithreaded programming in Java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call

```
search.run();
```

Call

```
new Thread(search).start();
```

instead.

In your actionPerformed you are just invoking method run in the current thread. If you call start() instead, it does the magic and starts the new thread that executes run().

Then you should modify the way you show result because you can't change UI in a thread that is not AwtEventQueue... you can consider something like this:

```
      //...

      // show result
      final String myResult=result;
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
         public void run(){
            JTF_address.setText(myResult);
         }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `actionPerformed` method, you block `Event Dispatch Thread` with long running task, because of your GUI freeze. For background processes you can use [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) or[`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). That will do task in background without freezing GUI.

Also read about [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).